# remove individuals based on their range of values

Tags: r, rows

I have a df with two variables, one with IDs and one with a variable called numbers. I would like to excude individuals who do not start their sequence of numbers with the number 1.

I have managed to do this by creating a binary indicator and excluding if the person has this indicator. However, there must be a simpler more elegant way to do this?

Example data and the code I've used to achieve desired result are below.

Thank you.

**sample df:**

```
zz<-"    names numbers
1   john       1
2   john       2
3   john       3
4   john       4
5   john       5
6   john       6
7   john       7
8   john       8
9   mary       4
10  mary       5
11  mary       6
12  mary       7
13  mary       8
14  mary       9
15  mary      10
16  mary      11
17  mary      12
18   pat       1
19   pat       2
20   pat       3
21   pat       4
22   pat       5
23   pat       6
24   pat       7
25   pat       8
26   pat       9
27   pat      10
28   sue       2
29   sue       3
30   sue       4
31   sue       5
32   sue       6
33   sue       7
34   sue       8
35   sue       9
36   tom       5
37   tom       6
38   tom       7
39   tom       8
40   tom       9
41   tom      10
42   tom      11
"

Data <- read.table(text=zz, header = TRUE)
```

**Step 1 - add binary indicator**

```
df$all<-ifelse(df$numbers==1, 1,0)
df$allperson<-ave(df$all, df$names, FUN=cumsum)
```

**Step two - get rid of people who do not have 1 as their start number**

```
df[!df$allperson==0,]
```

Comment: You don't really need to create the extra column. You could do it with just `Data[ ave(Data$numbers, Data$names, FUN=min) == 1, ]`. That might be the simplest using just base R. Are you interested in using other packages like `plyr`?

Comment: brilliant, thanks for that. i'm interested in everything - just want to try learn how to use R better :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want elegance, I must recommend the package `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

Data %>%
  group_by(names) %>%
  filter(min(numbers) != 1)
```

It means just what it appears to mean: filter only records where a group (defined by `names`) has a minimum `numbers` value inequal to 1.

```
   names numbers
1   mary       4
2   mary       5
3   mary       6
4   mary       7
5   mary       8
6   mary       9
7   mary      10
8   mary      11
9   mary      12
10   sue       2
11   sue       3
```

Answer (score 1):

You may also try:

```
zz1 <-  zz[with(zz, names %in% unique(names)[!!table(zz)[,1]]),]
head(zz1,4)
 #   names numbers
 #1   john       1
 #2   john       2
 #3   john       3
 #4   john       4
```